# Listeners duplicating when revisting page - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQM app with many pages, and I am moving it to jQM 1.4. I am using the new widgets/methods that are advised with 1.4, removing all deprecated code.

Consider a page with the following code:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#admin-edit-location', function(event, ui) {
        $('.edit-msg-groups', this).on('click', 'a', function () {
            $('<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" name="message_group[]" placeholder="Pool, Classes etc." data-mini="true"></div>').insertBefore($(".mg-btn-add"));
        });
});
```

If I goto the '#admin-edit-location' page, then naviagate elsewhere and then later go back to the '#admin-add-location' page and click that button...it inserts the div twice. If I leave the page again and come back later, then click the button it inserts 3 times etc..

I am looking for the way to prevent this from happening. I have all my pages in separate files.

EDIT: sample code for click events

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#view-wellness-tips", function (){
    var container = $('#admin-errors');
    $("#add_wellness_tip_form").validate({
        errorContainer: container,
        errorLabelContainer: $("ul", container),
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
        }
    });

    $('#add-new-tip').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
        var valid = $("#add_wellness_tip_form").valid();

        if(valid) {
            $('#add-tip').popup("close");
            $.mobile.loading("show");
            $.post("admin.php?v=wellness&x=add", $('#add_wellness_tip_form').serialize() , function(data) {
                $.mobile.loading("hide");
                if(data == 1) { //success
                    jqmRedirect("/admin.php?v=config&t=wellness-tips&newtip=true");
                } else { //fail
                    displayMessage(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

jqmRedirect:

```
function jqmRedirect(url){
var transitions = Array('slide', 'slideup', 'slidedown', 'pop', 'fade', 'flip', 'turn', 'slidefade');
var transiton = transitions[Math.floor(Math.random()*transitions.length)];

if(url == "reload"){
    $.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        transition : transiton,
        reverse : false,
        changeHash: false,
        allowSamePageTransition : true,
        reloadPage:true
    });
} else {
    $.mobile.changePage(url, {
        transition : transiton,
        reloadPage:true
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Use `.one("pagecreate"` although external pages are removed once navigated away, but the handlers/bound events aren't removed. Thus, you need to add listeners only once on `pagecreate`.

Comment: I know one potential fix is to use an "ID" rather than class, and use .click instead of on('click'), but I prefer to not go that route for several reasons, there are performance reasons for one thing, and also is i have this same listener on 3 pages then I have to create separate IDs for each page. It would be much more efficient and clean to stay with class selectors if possible, because if i ever need to modify the code I can do a project find and replace in my IDE and change all 3 at once. That's just some of the reasons/examples I prefer not to go the ID route

Comment: isn't the code i posted already using `.on('pagecreate'` ??

Comment: `.one` "1", not `.on`.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much. I mistook that as a typo, my apologies. Post as answer and I will mark correct. Thanks for helping me the several times you have with this transition to 1.4. I have worked with jQM since alpha and I was getting to the point of wanting to move to a different framework (due to my frustration with moving to 1.4), but this past week or so you have helped tremendously. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad your problem is solved.

Comment: As best practice, should `.click(function` events go into `.one("pagecreate"`  or `.on('pagecontainershow'` ?? I do not have any issue with these duplicating, but I just want to do what is correct

Comment: Use `pagecreate` to add listeners as it fires once per page. Use `pagecontainershow` to manipulate DOM, e.g. Show/hide div, add text, remove something...etc that you want to do whenever page is shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using a *Single Page Model*, pages are loaded via Ajax and then deleted when they are hidden. jQuery Mobile, removes external pages, but doesn't remove any binding.

When you show the page again, it gets loaded via Ajax once again and go through page creating process. Therefore, `pagecreate` will be emitted on the same page again resulting in multiplying the same event handlers.

To solve this problem, you have two options:

1. cache external pages by adding `data-dom-cache="true"` to page div. this will prevent page from being removed.
2. Listen to `pagecreate` only once using `.one()` not `.on()`, and add listeners during that stage.

   ```
   $(document).one("pagecreate", ".selector", function ()
   ```

Comment: I've run in to a problem with this method. I have a page where there is a button that opens a popup. The popup have a form and then is posted via ajax post. when the ajax returns i close the popup (in the code) and then reload the page. After the page reload the form in the popup will not submit. the button does not take any action. I think it is because the .on('click') within this .one() is no longer being listened for after the page reload (or after the first submit). How can I address this?

Comment: I have had so much trouble with listeners after navigation or page reload with 1.4. Should I just give up and redirect  in php and give up on dynamically updating the page, and/or changing page within jQuery mobile?

Comment: @live instead of one, use `.on()` and `$("#btnID").off("click").on("click", function () { });` put it inside `.on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function`.

Comment: @live no, don't give up there are solutions out there for any problem. Read this, this should help http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: is there any need for 'vclick click' or will just 'click' suffice?

Comment: I have followed your advice. It still does not work after the page reloads. The button click is not triggered at all, even if i remove the .off('click') part it does not trigger

Comment: @livewire1407 can you update your question with the code you're using. click is enough.

Comment: done. i had everything working at one point. not sure what happened but I have same issue on several pages

Comment: @livewire1407 okay, I will check it. Do you have life link?

Comment: I do but requires username and password. Can I reach you privately?

Comment: i will pay you if I have to, to do a join.me or something with be to iron out some of these issues so I can move forward

Comment: im thinking it may be something with pages where I reload to the same page, that's where I seem to be having problems. Maybe if you page transition to the same page you have to handle listeners differently? idk

Comment: would you have any time to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the handlers are not removed its that your using a delegated handler from document. I think a simpler solution is to just remove the pagecreate handler entirely and do

```
 $( "body" ).on('click', '.edit-msg-groups a', function () {
     $('<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" name="message_group[]" placeholder="Pool, Classes etc." data-mini="true"></div>').insertBefore($(".mg-btn-add"));
 });
```

This way you can use a single handler instead of 2.

Comment: Isn't that going to slow performance down since I have hundreds of pages, most with one or more events being handled?